# Gimp Opening file for reading: Permission Denied

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-mate, gimp

I get this when I try to open an image from within Engrampa.
I have no problems when using KolourPaint or Eye of Mate viewer.

It occurs with other zip files.

3/28/19 Update

```
andy@7_~$ lsof /home/andy/.cache/.fr-ZXEAGw/Headshot_Of_Me_3_25_19.png
andy@7_~$
```

[image]

Comment: So the other programs open the exact same file that GIMP doesn't open?

Comment: Yes. In  .cache -rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy 292112 Mar 25 15:33 Headshot_Of_Me_3_25_19.png @DK Bose

Comment: Try copying the file from the cache folder to another location like the desktop then try again.

Comment: I can open the file, but that doesn't help me. Engrampa should, as it has in the past, be able to open that image file. @Parto

Comment: As in, you can open the file with Engrampa from the Desktop but not from the cache folder?

Comment: Engrampa can not by itself open image files. The cache folder is just for temporarily storing the image file so Gimp can open it. @Parto

Answer (score 2):

I removed my Gimp snap and reinstalled Gimp using Synaptic.